# Billy has 5 books and 6 novels, in how many way can he pack 5 books so that at least 2 are novels?

Tags: combinatorics

So you'd work out in how many ways he can take 5 books with him

$11 \choose  5$

Then what? :/

Comment: Novels are books and books are what? Billy has $5$ books and $6$ novels and he picks $5$ books so that $2$ of the are novels? It seems like the answer is $0$! I guess there is something wrong with the wording.

Comment: The easiest way is to count separately taking $5,4,3,2$ novels. 5 novels ${6\choose5}$ ways, 4 novels ${6\choose4}{5\choose1}$, etc I am assuming that your first use of books in the title means something like "non-fiction books".

Comment: @Levant: Indeed, it seems that Billy has negative-one books that are not novels.

Comment: There is something wrong with the wording of your question.  All novels are books.  Do you mean five non-fiction books and six novels?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Billy has 5 non-novel books and 6 novels, with 5 spaces for books, and at least two must be novels, he can pack:

- 2 novels aka ${6 \choose 2}$
- 3 novels aka ${6 \choose 3}$
- 4 novels aka ${6 \choose 4}$
- 5 novels aka ${6 \choose 5}$

If he picks $n$ novels, then he has $5-n$ spaces left for books, which adds a factor of possibilities ${5 \choose 5-n}.$

Thus the desired answer is ${6 \choose 2}{5 \choose 3}+{6 \choose 3}{5 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 4}{5 \choose 1}+{6 \choose 5}{5 \choose 0} = 431.$

Comment: Please check my math I'm a pleb

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what you have, which is the total number of ways to pack $5$ items out of $11$.  (And it's correct.)

One way to get the answer to the question is to throw out all of the combinations that don't satisfy what you need.  Then, you're left with what you do need.

So if at least two of the items needs to be novels, then zero novels aren't enough, and one novel isn't enough.

There's only one way to pack zero novels, and that's to pack all five books.

Packing (exactly) one novel is a bit more involved.  First you pick the novel ($6$ choices) and then pick the four books ${5 \choose 4}$.

Then, your answer is

$$N = {11 \choose 5} - 1 - 6 \cdot {5 \choose 4}.$$